# How to retrieve attributes value with multiple level using Xml Linq?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<Menu>
    <Group Flow="Horizontal">
        <Item Text="Basket" >
        <Item Text="Favorites">
        <Item Text="Add" Roles="SuperAdmin">  
                <Item Text="Evaluation"  Roles="Admin">
                </Item>
                <Item Text="Titularisation" Roles="users,Admin">
                </Item>
        </Item>
    </Group>
</Menu>
```

and I want to retrieve all attributes **"Roles"**.

I tried this :

```
    XElement rootElement = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\TTM\Desktop\GeneralMenu.xml");
    XElement menuElt = rootElement.Element("Group");
    var itemsAdd = from el in menuElt.Descendants("Item")
                       where (string)el.Attribute("Text") == "Add"
                       select el;
    foreach (var item in itemsAdd)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("Roles").Value);
    }

    Console.Read();
```

but I get only the **"Roles"** of this balise:

```
<Item Text="Add" Roles="SuperAdmin">
```

Comment: You're only selecting items with Text="Add" to populate your itemsAdd-collection. So, yeah.

Comment: Yes. I know. I tried to do like this : `XElement itemAdd = from el in menuElt.Descendants("Item")
where (string)el.Attribute("Text") == "Add"
select el;` it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(XMLFile);
var itemAdd = xdoc.Descendants("Item")
                 .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Text") == "Add")
                 .Select(x => new
 {
    Roles = (string)x.Attribute("Roles"),
    ChildRoles = x.Descendants("Item")
                   .Select(z => (string)z.Attribute("Roles")).ToList()
 });
```

Here, `Roles` will contain the Roles from your parent node, and `ChildRoles` will hold all the Roles present in the descendants of parent where Text is Add.

You can then access them using `foreach` loop:-

```
foreach (var item in itemAdd)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Roles);
    foreach (var childRoles in item.ChildRoles)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(childRoles);
    }
}
```

If you want all the roles to be fetched in a single property then you can fetch it like this:-

```
Roles = x.Descendants("Item").Select(z => (string)z.Attribute("Roles"))
         .Concat(new List<string> { (string)x.Attribute("Roles") }).ToList()
```

Comment: Ok and how can I display the result ?

Comment: @mosflex -  Check my edit, on how to display the result.